# How to parse and list classes fields, constructors and methods that are used in a java file or code block?

Tags: programming-languages, java, syntax

I need to write a crawler to find sample java class,method and field usage. So I need a parser to parse a java source file (parsing of source code in incomplete form is much more better of course!) and return used classes, methods, fields in it.

```
public void methodName() {

   String s = new String("Test");

   int x = s.lastIndexOf("st");

}
```

In this example, I want to get that `String` class is used, its `String(String)` constructor and its `lastIndexOf(String)` method are called.

Answer (score 1):

Considered writing a Javadoc doclet which can do what you need?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/

Comment: I think javadoc APIs do not have main components that I need. Most important thing is to find the class of a variable that calls the methods or fields such as `s.split(b)`. all the work need to be done is to find type of s and b. However it gets tougher when we encounter `s.trim().split(x.getName())`. Note: it is enough for me to analyze only `s.split(b)` type of statements

Comment: If javadoc is not enough for what you need, you probably need a full Java compiler where you can hook into the result after parsing.